# Error function of complex value erf(ax+ib)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

How can I calculate erf of a complex value? For example:
$$\mathrm{erf}(ax+ib)$$
where $x$ is variable.

In fact my problem is simplification of below expression as a useful and implementable expression:
$$\mathrm{erf}(ax+ib)+\mathrm{erf}(ax-ib).$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the error function as an integral. $e^{-t^2}$ is holomorphic, so the integral is path independent and you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute it using the antiderivative. However, it is no easier to compute than for a real value, and there is no elementary expression for the antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, up to now, no special function have been defined and referenced in order to express on closed forms the integrals involved in the expression of the complex $ \mathbf{erf}(z)$
$$\mathbf{erf}(x+iy)=\frac{2}{\sqrt(\pi)}\big(e^{y^2}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\cos(2yt)dt+e^{-x^2}\int_0^y e^{t^2}\sin(2xt)dt\big)$$
$$-\frac{2 i}{\sqrt(\pi)}\big(e^{y^2}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\sin(2yt)dt-e^{-x^2}\int_0^y e^{t^2}\cos(2xt)dt\big)$$